# How can i handle negative value in reverse order in big decimal in java?

Tags: java, bigdecimal

I have one problem in `BigDecimal` with handling negative value in reverse order. I got a `NumberFormatException`. How can I solve it?

This is my code:

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;

public class Java_bigdecimal_signum {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        BigDecimal obj = new BigDecimal("20.15-");
        int i = obj.signum();
        System.out.println("\nobject value : " + obj
                         + "\nmethod generated value : " + i);
    }
}
```

Exception is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException
at java.math.BigDecimal.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.math.BigDecimal.<init>(Unknown Source)
at Java_bigdecimal_signum.main(Java_bigdecimal_signum.java:6)
```

I need output below:

```
object value : -20.15
method generated value : -1
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Just to clarify, I take it your not just passing a `String` 'literal' to BigDecimal in your **actual** code, right? Because if you are, you could just put the minus at the beginning instead.

Comment: why do you want to handle it in reverse order? You can process it before passing to `BigDecimal` constructor: `if(num.endsWith("-")){ num = "-" + num.substring(0, num.length() -1); }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I am assuming that your getting your number `String` with the minus on the end from somewhere else in your actual code, rather than passing a `String` literal to `BigDecimal`. If so, you can just process the `String` variable before passing it to BigDecimal, and move the `-` from the end to the beginning like so.

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;

public class Java_bigdecimal_signum {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String number = "20.15-";
        if(number.endsWith("-")){ 
            number = "-" + number.substring(0, number.length() -1); 
        }
        BigDecimal obj = new BigDecimal(number);
        int i = obj.signum();
        System.out.println("\nobject value : " + obj
                     + "\nmethod generated value : " + i);
    }
}
```

And, to state the obvious, If you really are just passing a `String` literal to `BigDecimal` as in your example code, then just put the minus on the beginning. `:)`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Rudi Kershaw. when i see the your response, that time i will do  like above coding. it's worked... thank you for your quick response.